# Element distortion with float:left

Tags: html, css, css-float

So what I am trying to do here is simply just align the sidebar and the table of images to be on the same line.

The problem is **not** with the alignment, the **main** problem here is that after inputting CSS command:

```
 float: left;
```

on the sidebar, the background narrows and the background colour does not extend the fully to cover the words.

CSS of sidebar starts at the first line of the CSS code while CSS for the tables of images is at the last line.

**Thanks a lot for your help !**

```css
/* sidebar menu */
#product_menu {
 position: relative;
 left: 8%;
 float: left;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
}

li {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border-bottom: 2px black;
}

.droplist {
 font-family: Arial; 
 font-size: 14px; 
 background-color: #7bc2eb;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .droplist {
    background-color: #68a3c5;}

/* list of images*/
#main {
 position: relative;
 left: 25%;
}
```

```html
  <aside id="product_menu">
   <ul>
    <li style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #68a4c7;">Products</li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M8</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="productwebpages/series/product_series.html">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M12</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Mini</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Standard</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Middle</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Large</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Quick</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
  </aside>

  
  <section id="main">
   <table id="product_table">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined `width:10%` to ul i.e it is restricting `ul` to pick background color

```css
/* sidebar menu */
#product_menu {
 position: relative;
 left: 8%;
 float: left;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border-bottom: 2px black;
}

.droplist {
 font-family: Arial; 
 font-size: 14px; 
 background-color: #7bc2eb;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .droplist {
    background-color: #68a3c5;}

/* list of images*/
#main {
 position: relative;
 left: 25%;
}
```

```html
  <aside id="product_menu">
   <ul>
    <li style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #68a4c7;">Products</li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M8</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="productwebpages/series/product_series.html">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M12</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Mini</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Standard</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Middle</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Large</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Quick</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
  </aside>

  
  <section id="main">
   <table id="product_table">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ul width or set width 100%.

```css
/* sidebar menu */
#product_menu {
 position: relative;
 left: 8%;
 float: left;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
 padding: 15px 20px;
 border-bottom: 2px black;
}

.droplist {
 font-family: Arial; 
 font-size: 14px; 
 background-color: #7bc2eb;
 border: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .droplist {
    background-color: #68a3c5;}

/* list of images*/
#main {
 position: relative;
 left: 25%;
}
```

```html
  <aside id="product_menu">
   <ul>
    <li style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; background-color: #68a4c7;">Products</li>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M8</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="productwebpages/series/product_series.html">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">M12</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Mini</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Standard</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Middle</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Large</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
    <li class="droplist">Quick</li>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
         <a href="">Phasellus porttitor</a>
       </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
  </aside>

  
  <section id="main">
   <table id="product_table">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
     <td>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x150/000/fff.jpg&text=image" alt="Image" width="150" height="150">
         <figcaption>Lorem Ipsum</figcaption>
      </figure>
     </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
  </section>
```